# hyperlink to specific tab on another page of same site

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have a set of tabs here: http://thetalbotcuckfield.co.uk/menus/

But I need to link to specific tabs from another page within the site e.g.
from here:http://thetalbotcuckfield.co.uk/whats-on/ the 'view menu' link will link through to the specific tab on the menu page.

The current query I have is as follows. It sets up the menus, but I can't figure a way to link through to specific tabs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
  });
  if (window.location.hash == "#tabs-container") {
    $(".tabs-menu > li").removeClass("current");
    $(".tabs-menu > li.xmas").addClass("current");
    $(".tab .tab-content").hide();
    $(".tab .tab-content#tab-5").fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Comment: can you format it readable?

Comment: You do have console errors: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slicknav is not a function` - the view menu seems to work in Chrome...